# Why is my AJAX code producing an error?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml, google-cdn

I have a little bit of ajax code to search through a xml file. It is working but I still get a strange error. Even the webconsole doesn't know in what file the error is.

My code:

```
var run = $.ajax({
 url: 'test.xml',
 dataType: 'xml'
}).done(function (xmlDoc) {
    xml = $(xmlDoc);

    result  = xml.find('product').find("name:contains('name_value')");
    $('body').append('<p>'+result.text()+'</p></br>');


    $('.a').text(xml.find('product').find('name').length); //displays the    amount of name tags in the xml file
});
```

my html:

```
<p class="a"></p> <!-- output paragraph of the last Jquery code line-->
```

My xml file structure

```
 <store>
    <product>
      <name> product name </name>
      <price> price </price>
      <platform> platform </platform>
    </product>
 </store>
```

and my error:

> **incorrectly formed     :1:77**

**edit**
He says the error occurs 2 times.

**edit 2** If I go to the network tab he only request jquery from google hosted libaries. That is the only thing I see there.

I am completly new to ajax and xml so can somebody tell what I am doing wrong

Comment: can you inspect the request/response using the network tab in your browser developer tools and share the response displayed there

Comment: is this the only error log you got.

Comment: @ArunPJohny added output to the question. (edit 2)

Comment: @KawineshSK Yes. the console is empty except thise error

Comment: are you sure your ajax request is being sent... add an alert stmt before `var run = $.ajax({` and see whether that is getting displayed

Comment: @ArunPJohny. I have no time tot test but i will do it. The code is werking hut i only het these errors. Another thing i run it local host

Comment: another thing you can try is `dataType: 'text'` then try to alert the value of `xmlDoc` before `xml = $(xmlDoc);`

Comment: Try adding `console.log(typeof xmlDoc)` to the start of your `done` function. Might be that since you're saying that the response is XML, jQuery is pre-parsing that for you and passing the jQuery object to the function, instead of the plain XML string, the same way it handles JSON.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks that works. When I alert `xmldoc` I get the xml file so that works and when I run the code the console is empty. Can you add this an answer to the question so that we can close the question.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know which browser you are using, as the errors reported will vary depending on, for example, if you are using Firefox or Chrome.

Let's assume the problem is in the .xml file itself (see below). If I take your code and set `dataType:'text'` (instead of `dataType:'xml'`) then I get no errors on Chrome, but I still get a single "not well-formed" error in Firefox.

```
$.ajax({        
    url : "test.xml",
    dataType : 'text',
    type : 'GET',
    timeout : 10000
})
.done(function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {                    
    xml = $(data);
    result = xml.find('product').find("name:contains('Eleventy')");
    $("body").append("<p>"+xml.text()+"</p>");
})
.fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
    console.log("Fail: " + textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
})
.always(function(a,textStatus,c){                    
});
```

Simplify your .xml file to a single product and see what happens:

```
<store>
  <product>
    <name EleventyOne </name>
    <price> Free </price>
    <platform> StackOverflow </platform>
  </product>
</store>
```

Here, the `<name>` tag is broken. Chrome doesn't complain if `dataType:'text'` but Firefox does. They both complain if `dataType:'xml'`. Neither complains if I change the filename from "test.xml" to "test.txt".

When dealing with problems like this, the best approach is to simplify the code/data as much as possible, in order to isolate the problem. If you reduce the xml file to a single product, which is clearly formatted correctly, and you still get the malformed error, then you know the data file itself is not the problem (which is unlikely but possible, I've had malformed errors reported in the past when the file itself was fine).